# Change URL paramaters parameters in request by id

Tags: python, django

I want to make urls with `GET` url pattern
`example.com/blog/?id=1`
my current code
**views.py**

```py
    def home(request,blog_uuid):
        blogs = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_uuid)
        return render(request,'home.html',{'blogs':blogs})
```

**url pattern**

```py
    path('blog/<blog_uuid>/',views.home,name='Blog'),
```

my current url now like this example.com/blog/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your url pattern to,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', views.home, name='Blog'),
    ...,
]
```

thrn change your view as

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def home(request):
    blog_uuid = int(request.GET.get("id", "-1"))
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_uuid)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'blogs': blog})
```